# Spring Security 5 replacement for OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods such as #oauth2.isUser() or #oauth2.isClient()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm looking for a replacement of `#oauth2.isUser()` (used in `@PreAuthorize` expressions) in Spring Security 5.x. It exists it Spring Security OAuth 2.x, but this library is deprecated.

The reason we need this is to require 3-legged tokens.

Comment: Did you found anything?

Comment: Did you find a solution? @Sergey

Comment: the same problem here..